# Clarifying a step in proving uniqueness of Jordan Decomp of signed measures

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This should be real simple but I have been struggling to see this in an easily intuitive manner. Basically, my confusion comes down to showing that if $A,B$ and $A',B'$ are two arbitrary Hahn decompositions and that if $v = v^+ - v^-$ is a signed measure that:

$v^+(E\cap A) = v^+(E\cap A')$

where E is an arbitrary set in the $\sigma$-algebra. I keep only being able to think about it by saying $E \cap A = (E \cap A')\cup N$ where $N$ is some null set since Hahn-Decompositions are unique except for null sets. Then I want to say that $v^+(E\cap A) = v^+(E\cap A') + v^+(N)$. But it isn't clear to me why $v^+(N) = 0$ for any null set $N$. ie $N$ would satisfy the criteria of a null set if $v^+(n) = v^-(n) \forall $ measurable $n \subset N$. What am I missing? What is the simplest way to show $v^+(E\cap A) = v^+(E\cap A')$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a Hahn decomposition $(A,B)$, the measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are defined by $\nu^+(E) = \nu(E \cap A)$ and $\nu^-(E) = -\nu(E \cap B)$. Given a second Hahn decomposition $(A',B')$ you must have
$$
\nu^+(B') = \nu(A \cap B') = 0 $$ because $A \cap B' \subset A$ implies $\nu(A \cap B') \ge 0$ and $A \cap B' \subset B'$ implies $\nu(A \cap B') \le 0$. Thus for any measurable $E$,
$$ \nu^+(E \cap A) = \nu^+(E) = \nu^+(E \cap A') + \nu^+(E \cap B') = \nu^+(E \cap A').$$